# Randomly show one item from the last x posted

Tags: views

I have worked out how to select a random item - add a sort criteria of type Global: Random. I can also select from, say, the last month, by adding a filter. However, if I want to select randomly from the last, say, 5 items posted, I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: Do you want to pick 1 random value from the last 5 item posted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort your View by ***Content: Post date (desc)*** and set the Pager to ***Use pager: Display a specified number of items | 5 items***

[image]

Go to the ***Advanced Settings*** in the view and click in the ***Theme: Information***

[image]

Search the ***Style output:*** section and select a name, in my case was views-view-unformatted--temp.tpl.php

Go to the folder `YOUR_SITE/sites/all/modules/views/theme` and copy to your theme folder the file `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` and rename it to **views-view-unformatted--temp.tpl.php**

Edit your new file `views-view-unformatted--temp.tpl.php` and put inside only this code to show only one element:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
 //Selecting one element from your last 5 posted elements
 $element = $rows[rand(0, 4)];
 $rows = array();
 $rows[] = $element;

?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the View go to the bottom of the Information window and click **Rescan template files** and click **OK**, then save your View.

[image]

And go to see your result.

**Attention:** Remember to repeat these steps if you ever change theme.

Comment: @James thanks James, a pleasure help you ;-)

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to get this to work with Drupal 8 - it doesn't have the "Theme: information" option in Views.

Comment: @James I don't know, I can't works yet with Views in Drupal 8. But if you found the answer let me know.

Comment: By the way, I think you should add a **Attention** near the end of your answer! to remember to repeat these steps if your ever change theme ... The down site of putting logic in themes, right?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thanks I edit now and go to the bed, here is 1:05am ;-)

Comment: Ok, back to EU now to keep drupal.SE alive (and monitor the review queues) while the other site of the Atlantic sleeps!

Comment: @James try using the Drupal 8 [Views Templates](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_templates) module

Comment: @NoSssweat How to use this module in Drupal 7?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, your answer is already using it. There is no 7 version as it comes with views already. For whatever reason they decided not to include the Theme: Information out of the box in Views 8.

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks ;-) I get the point +1 for you ;-)